# When using the R package Segue to connect to EMR I receive an S3 404 error

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, segue, emr

I'm trying to run my R code on EMR using the simple package Segue (https://code.google.com/p/segue).

I'm able to connect, however when I try to execute functions I get a 404 error relating to S3 (below). Can anyone speculate on what this means or how I might fix it? I have no knowledge of S3 and very little EMR experience.

Thanks!!

```
#Setup R Environment
setwd("/home/jmiller/") 
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("caTools")
install.packages("segue_0.05.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
install.packages("Matching")
library(rJava)
library(caTools)
library(segue)
library(Matching)

#Import raw data
data <- read.delim("STUFF GOES HERE ")

#Write the Function  
jdm <- function (data) {STUFF GOES HERE }

#Setup EMR
setCredentials("STUFF GOES HERE ", "STUFF GOES HERE ") 
> emr.test <- createCluster(numInstances=2 )
STARTING - 2013-10-30 13:50:33
STARTING - 2013-10-30 13:51:05
STARTING - 2013-10-30 13:51:36
STARTING - 2013-10-30 13:52:07
STARTING - 2013-10-30 13:52:38
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2013-10-30 13:53:09
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2013-10-30 13:53:40
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2013-10-30 13:54:12
WAITING - 2013-10-30 13:54:43
Your Amazon EMR Hadoop Cluster is ready for action. 
Remember to terminate your cluster with stopCluster().
Amazon is billing you!

> emr.result <- emrlapply(emr.test, data, jdm, taskTimeout=10)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Status Code: 404, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: F39B3FDE8682AF39, AWS   Error Code: NoSuchBucket, AWS Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist, S3 Extended Request ID: g9XDhofkpgux2/mBR4t8FhY3u9G85ZxsvXZkr1SZ2a0bA871LJKNSqtgeAfaFEG0

> stopCluster(emr.test)
```

So after shutting that cluster down I spun up another cluster and tried to run Jeff Breen's example. To my great surprise, it actually worked on my first attempt.

> outputEmr   <- emrlapply(myCluster, myList, mean,  na.rm=T)
>   RUNNING - 2013-10-30 16:22:03
>   RUNNING - 2013-10-30 16:22:34
>   RUNNING - 2013-10-30 16:23:06
>   WAITING - 2013-10-30 16:23:37

**but** I then tried to use my own function on the same cluster and it failed with the same error message as before **and** at that point I deleted the result of the example and tried it again. That produced the same 404 error message again.

> outputEmr   <- emrlapply(myCluster, myList, mean,  na.rm=T)
>   Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
>     Status Code: 404, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 8379F458DD96EC9B, AWS Error Code: NoSuchBucket, AWS Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist, S3 Extended Request ID: 1hjGApzfy5rd5JaM+mhhg35C/DUJ0qSa5V2uGXLjCV3tjTLfSUrM7zqsUCFKHCFH

So I shut down the cluster and spun up another, again running only the example code. That gave me the 404 error again. I tried it another 2 times and got the same error.

My understanding from the Segue Google group is that the author JD Long is aware of another few users and myself having this problem and he's investigating it, but as of now we don't know what's broken or how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 means the AWS connection string isn't correct.  It's hard to tell what URL you provided to connect.

I see these lines in Jeffrey Breen's example, but not in your code:

```
> library(segue)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: caTools
Loading required package: bitops
Segue did not find your AWS credentials. Please run the setCredentials() function.

> setCredentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

> myCluster <- createCluster(numInstances=5)
```

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/404error.htm

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/segue-r-to-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-hadoop/

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, I did successfully connect with my AWS credentials and load the required packages. I'll update the main post with that. While you'll see me load some of the packages myself they are also loaded within the source code of the Segue package.